# How can I apply changes to user permissions across several sites?

Tags: users, drush

I am using Drupal 7, we have a total of 99 different instances of pretty much the same site.  All sites have the user roles of adm_core and mgr_center.

We are currently using drush and puppet to apply changes/updates across sites.

What I'm wondering is if there is a drush command that I can use to just give adm_core the same privileges as mgr_center?

If not does anyone have suggestions on the best method to do this across all sites short of going and changing permissions site-by-site?

Comment: If there are the same set of users on each site, and each have the same UID you could just copy the users_roles table?

Comment: @FelixEve: Wouldn't it be more the role_permission table instead of the user_roles table.

Comment: @rooby Yes, your right. users_roles = which users have which roles, role_permission = which permissions belong to each role

Answer (score 0):

I found [this snippet](http://dropbucket.org/node/348) for copying permissions from one role to another, which you can easily rewrite to a `drush sql` command and integrate in your current workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a little PHP script utilizing drupal core functions to add certain permissions to those two roles and execute that script with drush scr on all 99 sites.